# Is there a way to have Crystal Reports prompt user for their e-mail address then result set is e-mailed to user as a spreadsheet?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm new to Crystal Reports, and I have a SQL report that previously has been run in SMSS by the person in my position and e-mailed out on demand. I'd like to put it in Crystal Reports so users can run when needed; Crystal Reports is integrated with our EHR system. The report has way too many columns to fit on a page which sets the user up for complaints when the report doesn't print correctly. I'm wondering if there's some way that I can set a parameter or similar that prompts the user for an e-mail address and Crystal Reports then e-mails the report as a spreadsheet/csv file versus displaying it for print. Could a python program be triggered in some way and thus bypass CR? Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible via the Crystal Reports runtime. Or consider getting one of the 3rd-party Crystal Reports automation tools listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched).